# Why is my dependency container variable undefined when I try to register csrf middleware for all routes in Slim?

Tags: slim, middleware

I am trying to register middleware for all routes to protect against csrf in Slim. I have installed the files for Slim csrf protection using composer and I have added the dependency to my dependencies file, but when I try to register the middleware in my middleware file, I get an error telling me that my dependency container variable is undefined.

I am a programming newbie and do not understand how to troubleshoot things within a framework. So I have just tried fiddling with it.

Dependency in dependencies.php:

```
$container['csrf'] = function ($c) {
        return new \Slim\Csrf\Guard;
};
```

Register middleware in middleware.php:

```
use Slim\App;

return function (App $app) {
    $app->add($container['csrf']);
};
```

It should work, especially considering I literally did exactly what the documentation says to do in order to set this up, but when I refresh my page after I get a notice message telling me $container is not defined. Because I am completely new to using a framework I could really use some insight. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you define `$container` in dependencies.php? Is the above code, all that is included in middleware.php?

Answer (score 1):

The `App` is not the container itself; it holds the container, so you need to get at it first.

Try:

```php
return function (App $app) {
    $app->add($app->getContainer()->get('csrf'));
};
```

Note that I've also used the `get()` method on the container for retrieval. This is the method that PSR-11 uses and so will work with a variety of containers. Using array access to retrieve items from the container is Pimple specific.